# Extending cakephp auth component with extra conditions

Tags: cakephp-2.0

Problem: I want to show different error messages to user based on user status on login (using ajax). For ex: If the user status is pending, I want to show one message, or else if the user status is disabled, I want to show another message. Only active user should be able to login.

After some searching found that I can use

1. identify method

   or
2. I should use write my conditions inside "`if
   ($this->Auth->login())`" condition in my login method.

If I use 1st method in custom component (which will extend auth), hope it can only return true or false, right ? Can it set error messages and return, so that I can get it from my controller ?

If I use 2nd method after allowing the user to login I should check the status and if it is not active, I should remove the login credentials from Auth/Session. how can I do that ? Is this a  good method ?

Any other better solution ? Im using cakephp2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a class extending from BaseAuthenticate for your users and set this up within your AppController.

```
public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => ..... ,
        'logoutRedirect' => ..... ,
        'loginAction' => ..... ,
        'authenticate' => array('YourUsers'),
    )
);
```

And then create the class

```
<?php
App::uses('BaseAuthenticate', 'Controller/Component/Auth');

class YourUsersAuthenticate extends BaseAuthenticate {

    public function authenticate(CakeRequest $request, CakeResponse $response) {
        // your code goes in here
    }
}
```

You can return false from within the authenticate to deny the user access or can return an object on success that will get stored in $this->Auth->user which you can interogate later.

If you get stuck, the [CookBook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html) has a lot of detail about this.

Comment: I create like above and return User data in `authenticate`, but refresh page always logout me and static `AuthComponent::user()` is empty